# Java - Using a breakpoint on this method

Tags: java, breakpoints

This is a question from a past exam paper. The code was given in the question and i need to gain the values and how many times the breakpoint is it. I have tried running the code in eclipse but to no avail. (I could find the values in debug mode if code executed)

Also the question states that: the method `fact` is called on an instance of the class in which `n` has the value 6. Not sure what I am doing wrong as the code is exactly the same as given in the question.

```
public class FactLoop {

private int n;// assumed to be greater than or equal to 0

/**
 * Calculate factorial of n
 * 
 * @return n!
 */
public int fact() {
    int i = 0;
    int f = 1;

    /**
     * loop invariant 0<=i<=n and f=i!
     */

    while (i < n) {// loop test (breakpoint on this line)
        i = i++;
        f = f * i;
    }
    return f;
}

// this main method is not a part of the given question
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FactLoop fl = new FactLoop();
    fl.n = 6;
    System.out.println(fl.fact());
}
```

`}`

Comment: @OsamaJaved and david - the break point is mentioned in his question in the code -  while (i < n) {// loop test (breakpoint on this line). Looking at it quickly it looks like it should loop 6 times - 0 through to 5

Comment: What do you think `i = i++;` does?

Comment: when i run this code in eclipse, with a breakpoint on the `while(i<n)` line my values are just 0. Not sure why this is

Comment: @nsc010 See explanation by "Alex Coleman"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error is in `i=i++;`. `i++` increments i, and retuns i's old value. By saying `i=i++`, you increment it, then set it to its old value.

Just use `i++;` to increment it.

Comment: Additionally `++i` would give him the result he wants.

Comment: Do you mean `i=++i`? If so, yeah, but it's sort've redundant. If you just mean plain old `++i;`, then yeah. The only difference is it returns its incremented value, as opposed to `i++` which returns the value before incrementing

Comment: That has worked, I missed that error and the explanation makes sense. Thanks for that.

Comment: @nsc010 Yup, happy to help :)